# android: sliding tabs inside scrollview

Tags: android-layout, android-tabs, android-scrollview, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a requirement where I have tabs in the middle of the page and I want to be able to scroll the page first before the contents of the tabs (See Dailymotion app or Google+ app).

I'm able to add tabs in the middle using the following layout below but how do I get that scrolling effect where the entire screen scrolls first until the tabs reach to the top and then the contents inside the tabs scroll?

```
<ImageView .../>
<com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout   ../>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager   ../>
```

[image]

Comment: can u share your code,if you had implemented successfully.